# making text appear on top of faded image

Tags: css

The solution is probably really simple but ahhh I just can't get it. I have a div with text in it which I placed right at the same location of an image. What is supposed to happen, and it does, is the image is supposed to fade out allowing the text to be more visible. The only thing is though, that I want the text to be hidden, and made visible only when the user hovers over the image/div text box. I tried a few things like

```
.display {
visibility: hidden;
}

img.artwork:hover + .display {
visibility: visible; 
}
```

but that doesn't work because it just starts glitching. I can't use z-index either because neither the image nor the div text are in position: absolute or position: relative. Any ideas on how to fix this? This is what I have right now:

```
img.albumartwork:hover{
        opacity: .15;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    }


.display {

    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    color: rgb(220,221,229);
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -120px;
    margin-left: 52.5px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);

}
```

Comment: you can still use z-index with position relative

Comment: try to target color property on your :hover

Comment: a fiddle would be super helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

try to target color property on your `:hover`

[SAMPLE](http://codepen.io/qtgye/pen/EyuJk)

```
div {     
  color: transparent;
  transition: 0.5s all ease ;
}

div:hover {  
  color: black;  
}

div:hover img {
  opacity: 0;
}

img {
  width: 150px;
  transition: 0.5s all ease ;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```